# SQL timeseries inserts with ability to update known observations

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

I'm experimenting with time-series and have the data in a Postgres database table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.time_series(
id integer NOT NULL,
datetime timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
value real NOT NULL,
edit_datetime timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now())
```

Now when I insert data from Python I create a temp table and insert it into the main table where this observation doesn't exist.

```
INSERT INTO time_series(id, datetime, value) 
            SELECT temp_time_series.id, temp_time_series.datetime, temp_time_series.value
            FROM temp_time_series
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 'X' 
            FROM time_series
                 WHERE temp_time_series.id = time_series.id
                 AND temp_time_series.datetime = time_series.datetime
                 AND temp_time_series.value = time_series.value)"""
```

It seems to be working very fast which it needs to.

What if I have a case where I just want to update a time-series observation with a new value and update the edit timestamp, instead of inserting a new row?
I don't have any primary key, and sometimes I need to have older versions of the DateTime but with different edit_datetimes. So I don't know if it will work with creating a constraint-based on id and DateTime, which I also don't know how to do or how to edit the code to handle.

Does anybody with any advice?

BR

Comment: You need a way to identify the row, and every table should have a primary key.

Comment: Thanks for the comment regarding primary key @LaurenzAlbe 
I have read some more stuff about why that is a good idea. 
Im still having some trouple in regards to both be able to insert data for the same period and update the observation for that period.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/schema-management/indexing/#best-practices) is a good resource to show you how to add the index.

You can also see how [upsert](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/write-data/upsert/#upsert-functionality) works and use the `ON CONFLICT` clause along with the index.

```sql
INSERT INTO time_series VALUES (...)
  ON CONFLICT (time, id) DO UPDATE
  SET value = excluded.value;
```

Comment: Ahhh but with the  (dateimetime, id) index inplace. I would not be able to add another row with the same id and datetime (but different edit_datetime and value), and I would like to be able to choose from insert to insert,  between updating if the datetime, id combination exists AND inserting  new row with different value and edit_datime despite the datetime, id already exist

Comment: Would change the ` ON CONFLICT (time, id) DO UPDATE` to ` ON CONFLICT (time, id, edit_datetime) DO UPDATE` approach it properly?